# Variadic template iteration and GCC

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, variadic-templates

I've implemented a variadic template function according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template#C.2B.2B). And iterate it with help of "overloading with "termination versions" of functions". The code:

```
void writeValue(QDataStream& /*data*/) {}

template<typename A, typename... Values>
void writeValue(QDataStream& data, const A& arg1, const Values&... args)
{
    data << arg1;
    writeValue(data, args...);
}

template<typename... Values>
quint32 PrepareMessage(QDataStream& data, func_code fcode, Values... parameters)
{
  data << quint32(fcode);
  writeValue(data, parameters...);
  return 0;
}
```

It can be build and used without any problems with Qt 5.5 for Windows over MSVC2013 64bit toolchain.
Now I'm trying to build the same code on Linux with Qt 5.5 for Linux over GCC 64 bit and getting following errors at compilation:

```
g++ -c -pipe -std=c++11 -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -D_64bit -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../Trans2QuikWrapper -I. -I../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include -I../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtNetwork -I../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I../../../Qt/5.5/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o moc_T2Q_Client.o moc_T2Q_Client.cpp
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/home/truf/Qt/5.5/gcc_64 -Wl,-rpath,/home/truf/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib -o t2q T2Q_Client.o main_client.o moc_T2Q_Client.o   -L/home/truf/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Network -lQt5Core -lpthread 
main_client.o: In function `int QGenericAtomicOps<QBasicAtomicOps<4> >::load<int>(int const&)':
/home/truf/.wine/drive_c/build-t2q-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/../Trans2QuikWrapper/io_utils.h:16: multiple definition of `writeValue(QDataStream&)'
Makefile:192: recipe for target 't2q' failed
T2Q_Client.o:/home/truf/.wine/drive_c/build-t2q-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/../Trans2QuikWrapper/io_utils.h:16: first defined here
moc_T2Q_Client.o: In function `int QGenericAtomicOps<QBasicAtomicOps<4> >::load<int>(int const&)':
/home/truf/.wine/drive_c/build-t2q-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/../Trans2QuikWrapper/io_utils.h:16: multiple definition of `writeValue(QDataStream&)'
T2Q_Client.o:/home/truf/.wine/drive_c/build-t2q-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_GCC_64bit-Debug/../Trans2QuikWrapper/io_utils.h:16: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [t2q] Error 1
```

gcc version is 5.2.1 20151010 (Ubuntu 5.2.1-22ubuntu2). Wine is not involved - just a folder location.

Are variadic templates supported there? Any additional compilation parameters needed? Or roblem is in code?

Comment: You can implement this without "recursion": https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5d766dc156529d0fd49d

Comment: This has nothing to do with variadic templates. It's a simple problem of where to define functions.

Comment: @Simple: or in C++17: `(data << ... << args);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says:

> multiple definition of `writeValue(QDataStream&)'

To solve this, you must declare `writeValue()` as `inline`:

```
inline void writeValue(QDataStream& /*data*/) {}
```

When you **define** a function in a header file, you *always should* mark it as `inline`. This way, it won't break the [ODR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) if you `include` the header in multiple translation units.